# multiple nodes in a Hyperledger fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I want to create a non-simulation Hyperledger Fabric environment using multiple Raspberry pi's etc.
How can I implement this with multiple nodes in a Hyperledger fabric?

Most searches and questions are based on First Network, which was used in the old version, so I would like to know if there are any websites that can help me based on the newer version.